# Sum or bounds of $\sum\frac{1}{a^n+b^n}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis

I will keep it short as I have made $0$ progress on the problem (both solving it and researching) and am just interested. Is there any closed form or non-trivial bounds (so tighter than $1 + \frac{1}{a - 1}$) on the sum $\sum\frac{1}{a^n + b^n}$ where $a > 1$? Clearly it converges by a comparison test.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: What do you know about $b$? Is it positive?

Comment: @PierreCarre Yep,

Comment: $a^n + b^n = \prod_1^n (a-b\omega_i) $ where $\omega_i$ are the $n$th roots of $-1$, then use partial fractions?

Comment: @Tavish How would you compute $\frac{1}{a+b} + \frac{1}{(a+bi)(a-bi)} + \frac{1}{(a+b)(a+b\omega)(a+b\omega^2)} + \ldots$? I don't see how partial fraction will help (cancel stuff out)?

Comment: @Tavish Do you mind doing a small example with either $\sum\frac{1}{a^n+1}$ or $\sum\frac{1}{a^n-1}$? I don't quite understand the exchange summation order part

Comment: @GarethMa Nevermind actually. That does give an alternate representation of the sum, but it doesn’t seem to simplify.

Comment: There's no reason to expect a closed form, even for such a simple example as $a=2$, $b=1$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can suppose $b<a$. I´ll assume too that the sum begins in $n=1$, so the obvious lower bound (with $b=0$) is $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{a^n}=\frac{1}{a-1}$. I don´t know if there is an exact way to find the sum, but one way I found to get upper/lower bounds as tight as you want uses this equality:

$$\frac{1}{a^n+b^n}=\frac{1}{a^n}-\frac{b^n}{a^n}\frac{1}{(a^n+b^n)}.$$

Using it, you can deduce:

$$\displaystyle\sum\frac{1}{a^n+b^n}=
\sum\frac{1}{a^n}-\sum\frac{b^n}{a^n}\frac{1}{(a^n+b^n)}=
\sum\frac{1}{a^n}-\sum\frac{b^n}{a^{2n}}+\sum\frac{b^{2n}}{a^{2n}}\frac{1}{a^n+b^n}
=$$

$$=\sum\frac{1}{a^n}-\sum\frac{b^n}{a^{2n}}+\sum\frac{b^{2n}}{a^{3n}}-\sum\frac{b^{3n}}{a^{3n}}\frac{1}{a^n+b^n}=\cdots$$

Calling $\displaystyle s_k=\sum\frac{b^{kn}}{a^{kn}}\frac{1}{(a^{n}+b^n)}$, it´s easy to see that $s_k$ tends to $0$ when $k$ goes to infinity (as the greater sequence $t_k=\sum\frac{b^{kn}}{a^{kn}}$ goes to $0$).

So, $\displaystyle\sum\frac{1}{a^n+b^n}=\sum\frac{1}{a^n}-\sum\frac{b^n}{a^{2n}}+\sum\frac{b^{2n}}{a^{3n}}+\dots=\sum_{k=0}^\infty(-1)^k\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{b^{kn}}{a^{(k+1)n}}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty(-1)^k\frac{\frac{b^{k}}{a^{(k+1)}}}{1-\frac{b^{k}}{a^{(k+1)}}}=$

$$=\sum_{k=0}^\infty(-1)^k\frac{b^k}{a^{k+1}-b^k}.$$

The difference between this sequence and the initial one is that this one is alternating, and its terms are decreasing in absolute value. This implies that, calling the partial sums $S_n=\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^k\frac{b^k}{a^{k+1}-b^k}$, $S_n$ will be an upper bound for the limit when $n$ is even, and a lower bound when $n$ is odd. Thus for example you have the upper bound

$S_2=\frac{1}{a-1}-\frac{b}{a^2-b}+\frac{b^2}{a^3-b^2}$, it is smaller than the obvious upper bound $\frac{1}{a-1}$ (which is $S_0$).

In general taking $S_n$ with $n$ even and big enough will give you upper bounds as tight as you want, and the same for lower bounds taking $n$ odd.\

Edit: After thinking again this seems pretty useless because you will probably get similar bounds just using the obvious upper bounds $K_n:=\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{1}{a^i+b^i}+\frac{1}{a^{i+1}(a-1)}$.

Comment: I will take a look tomorrow and see, but $S$ seems to be better bounds than $K$ at first glance.

Answer (score 3):

We do have this, in terms of [Jacobi theta functions](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/JacobiThetaFunctions.html):
For $a>1>b>0$,
\begin{align}
&\sum_{n=-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{a^n+b^n}
=
\frac{\vartheta_2(i\log(a)/2,\sqrt{b/a}\,)\vartheta_2(0,\sqrt{b/a}\,)
\vartheta_3(0,\sqrt{b/a}\,)\vartheta_4(0,\sqrt{b/a}\,)}
{2i\;\vartheta_1(i\log(a)/2,\sqrt{b/a}\,)\vartheta_1(\pi/2,\sqrt{b/a}\,)}
\end{align}

Comment: See https://mathoverflow.net/a/186315/454

Comment: Wow here’s the WTF answer i was looking for :) thank you, i will take a look at that.

Comment: The theta functions are defined as infinite series, so this formula replaces the evaluation of one infinite series with the evaluation of six of them.

Comment: @GerryMyerson do you know anything about the convergence rate comparison?

Comment: Sorry, don't think this helps me a lot, since I can't even code it correctly after following the definitions on the mathworld page (and crosschecking the special values)...

Comment: Sorry, I don't know how the convergence rates compare.